# Why am I getting an "IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled" here?

Tags: c#, combobox, selectedindexchanged, indexoutofrangeexception, valuemember

comboBoxWeekToSchedule has 13 entries in it when I select the one at index 3 (the fourth item in comboBoxWeekToSchedule). Yet a "*IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled*" exception is thrown.

Here is the code that runs which is throwing the exception (on the first line of the handler):

```
private void comboBoxWeekToSchedule_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs eargs)
{
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(comboBoxWeekToSchedule.ValueMember[comboBoxWeekToSchedule.SelectedIndex]);
    DisableICRVBS(AYttFMConstsAndUtils.IsFirstWeekOfMonth(dt));            
}
```

The values in comboBoxWeekToSchedule are dates in LongDateString format; the one in particular I chose is "Monday, March 7, 2016"

So how is it that SelectedIndex could possibly be out of range?

Comment: Have you actually checked the value of `SelectedIndex`? Is it 3 or perhaps it isn't set yet because you are in the selection callback...

Comment: Exactly.. you are in the callback. Check the 'comboBoxWeekToSchedule.SelectedIndex' value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValueMember` is a string. It is used by the `ComboBox` control to retrieve (using reflection) the value that is associated with a particular element when you use the `comboBoxWeetToSchedule.SelectedValue` property. So you might set it something like `"Date"` and when you reference `SelectedValue` you will really be retrieving the `SelectedItem`'s `Date` property.

Doing an index on that string will retrieve the 'nth' character which I am sure is not what you want to do. Since you have not provided any code that sets `ValueMember`, I can only assume that you are setting it to a string of 3 characters or less, which is why it is falling over.

What you really want to do in your code is retrieve the value instead:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(comboBoxWeekToSchedule.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: "I can only assume that you are setting it to a string of 3 characters or less"; no, as mentioned, they are values such as "Monday, March 7, 2016"

Comment: I was not talking about the values put into the combobox, but about the value of ValueMember itself. It is afterall only a string that acts as 'lookup' into the property of the values themselves. If you were to put a breakpoint on the originally failing assignment and examine the value of `ValueMember` you will find that it is a string less than 4 characters long (it might even be null, if you never assigned a value to it - in which case SelectedValue would simply return the SelectedItem).